# Lost Identity api when updating to ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity

Today, I upgraded my projects to netcoreapp 2.1 to 2.2.
After that, my projects using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity give me an error:
error CS0234: The name or namespace name 'Identity' does not exist in the 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

If I add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity nuget package in project reference, I don't have any error with using directive, but I have always error on cannot found IdentityUser
I also cleaned nuget cache on my machine

My code is here: https://github.com/SOFTINUX/Base
(If, you would try to reproduce, you need to restore npm packages in Barebone project before build)

So, in netcoreapp 2.2, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity is not found. With netcoreapp2.1, I have no problems.

I want to use Identity into my app with netcore2.2, but I not found any informations about changes on it and I tested with example app in netcoreapp2.2  and I have no problem with it.
I supppose, the problem come from my project, but I dont see nothing

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Xarkam; let me take a look at this today :)

Comment: There are also a few other bits and bolts missing from your WebApplication project, like `Microsoft.aspnetcore.staticfiles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just cloned it and tried building it. 
The error shows, that the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` is missing in the `SoftinuxBase.Security.Data.Entities` project and that the compiler cannot find a reference for `IdentityUser<T>` and `IdentityRole<T>` both of which reside inside the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` package.

So to resolve your error add the this package to your entities project, either through project reference or package manager console:

```
install-package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity -ProjectName SoftinuxBase.Security.Data.Entities

install-package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore -ProjectName SoftinuxBase.Security.Data.Entities
```

The EntityFrameworkCore package has a dependency on the base Identity package and should pull that in implicitly, I've just added in the install-package command for clarity. In theory you should get away with just pulling in The EF package.

After getting rid of all the other small issues like the missing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` package, I can compile the solution and get greeted by the following browser window:

[image]

So I suppose that this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the time you gave to help me. I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Stores for more precision. It's unfortunate not to have a correct changelog to see the changes made from one version to another. I will still have to fight with my applicationBuilderExtension for everything to work.